# One-to-one bidirectional relationship query

Tags: sql, activerecord

I'm working with Rails and I have a `Link` ActiveRecord model with this table:

```
create_table "links", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name",        :null => false
  t.integer  "sender_id",   :null => false
  t.integer  "receiver_id", :null => false
end

add_index "links", ["name"], :name => "index_links_on_name"
add_index "links", ["sender_id", "receiver_id"], :name => "index_links_on_sender_id_and_receiver_id", :unique => true
```

What I would like to do is to SELECT every links WHERE `name = "follow"` which exist from the source to the destination AND from the destination to the source.

For instance, having the following entries:

```
id | name     | sender_id | receiver_id
---------------------------------------
66 | "follow" | 1         | 2
67 | "follow" | 2         | 1
68 | "follow" | 1         | 3
69 | "fuu"    | 3         | 1
70 | "bar"    | 2         | 25
71 | "bar"    | 25        | 2
```

...I would like to just get `66` and `67` ids as a result.  Because sender_id `1` and receiver_id `67` are linked from source to destination and also from destination to source (with a "follow" name in both cases).

Can we do it, with just one SQL query (in SQL directly or ActiveRecord ORM)? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Following Query>>

```
select * from tablename t1,t2 where t1.sender_id = t2.receiver_id and t2.sender_id=t1.receiver_id and Name like follow"
```

Comment: And, of course, make sure that you have the appropriate indexes on the table.  Without indexes, this will be a dog-slow query if there is a lot of data.  (Use `EXPLAIN` to see what plan the query planner generates.)

Comment: @cdhowie : May be u r right...but my intesion was to just give direction to thoughts about the query writting in these cases..

Comment: Yes, my comment was not directed at you, but just to supply some information regarding performance to any readers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I'm gonna add an index on: `name`, `sender_id,receiver_id`, `sender_id`, `receiver_id`, `sender_id,name` and `receiver_id,name` (where `sender_id,receiver_id` index is also unique).